# Can't assign Value to php date Box

Tags: javascript, php

Hi everyone I'm trying to manually assign a value to an html date input field. But it doesn't work.

First I tried to pass the value the way I do it for ordinary input box

```
<?php $newDate2 = '03/31/2014'; ?>
<form name='RegForm' method='GET'>
<input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate" value="<?php echo $newDate2; ?>" required>
</form>
```

When It didn't work I tried to Use Javascript width something like this:

```
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function showInvoiceDate(){
   var mYDate = new Date('2011-04-11');
   alert(mYDate);
   document.getElementById("sdate").value=mYDate;
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="showInvoiceDate();">
  <form name='RegForm' method='GET'>
  <input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate" required>
  </form>
</body>
```

The function is being prompted. Because Alert box shows the value of `myDate` But the value of date box is not being changet its still `mm/dd/yyy`

So What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: I wonder is it possible to manually assign value of a Date Box at all?

Comment: Define? What do you mean?

Comment: what is a "date box"?

Comment: You're trying to set a ***date object*** as the value of an input

Comment: What I mean by Date Box is `<input type="date"`

Comment: Yes Whats a problem about it? It takes value, I can pass this value to a database. But to assign value to it causes me troubles

Comment: o how can I set the value of a Date Object?

Comment: `<input type="date" ...` is not acting as a "date control" but as a simple text input currently. see http://jsfiddle.net/xB88P/

Comment: @adeneo - this is invoking an implicit `...toString()` IMHO and thus giving the default format

Comment: So Alex What shall I do than?

Comment: The question is: what do you expect other than filling a text box with a formated date string?

Comment: Guess: you want to populate the java script date object with the value from the php variable and afterwards assign that to the input box, right?

Comment: well I expect it to have a value that I assign to it. With a possibility to pass this value if submit is presses

Comment: but apparently can't pass a value to it at all

Comment: So Alex ShallI change value to string?

Comment: The date should be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: I tried `newDate2` to string by using `(string)newDate2` but its still not working

Comment: Is it really possible to pass value to it?

Comment: Joshua Shall I change it in Javascript or I can do it in PHP?

Comment: Hold On. Let me try it.

Comment: if I try to put it in`YYYY-MM-DD ` format it gives me this output: `2014201420142014-MarMar-MonMon`

Comment: how can I change it to `YYYY-MM-DD`? i did it like this `$newDate2 = date("YYYY-MM-DD", strtotime('2011-04-11'));`

Comment: Yes Alex You are Right. But I want to use javascript because I can't assign value directly to the INput

Comment: Thats the onlt reason I use Javascrpt

Comment: ALLELUIA!!! I figure it out. The problem was the format of the date the correct way to do it is `$newDate2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2011-04-11'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date should be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Single digit days and months should be padded with a 0. January is 01.

From the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value):

> A string representing a date.
> Value: A valid full-date as defined in [[RFC 3339]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), with the additional qualification that the year component is four or more digits representing a number greater than 0.

**PHP** - code should be:

```
<?php $newDate2 = "2014-03-31"; ?>
<form name='RegForm' method='GET'>
<input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate" value="<?= $newDate2; ?>" required>
</form>
```

Tested and it works for me.

**Javascript** - you need to construct the date string, then set it, like:

```
var dateString = mYDate.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + (mYDate.getUTCMonth()+1) + "-" + mYDate.getUTCDate();
document.getElementById("sdate").value = dateString ;
```

I didn't test the JS version, but it should work.